# Google sitelinks

Tags: seo, google-search, search-results, sitelinks

How can I get Google to display sitelinks under search results when my website shows up?

When my website shows up in position 1 which it does for a couple of keywords it displays sitelinks, but whenever we show up in any other position than the first one, we don't have any sitelinks displayed at all.

I know it's not a matter of just being in the top position or not because I see sites all the time that are in any number of position in the search results and occasionally I'll see a site that has sitelinks even though they're like half way down page 3 or something..

[image]

Answer (score 0):

They appear over time. If you have good content and relevant pages, Google will show them. You can not add them youself, you can only request removal if you don't like the ones displayed.

Get your overall SEOrank up, and create some important relevant pages which rank good, and if you lucky, they'll appear.

They decide which pages get those links, so it's not guaranteed all your pages get it.